# Get Deleted Object in AbstractMongoEventListener

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to run some logic when an Object get deleted from MongoDB. I am using SpringData Mongo.

I am using AbstractMongoEventListener as the object can be deleted from collection through number of ways and I am overriding the

```
public void onBeforeDelete(BeforeDeleteEvent<Object> event)
```

method. But there are no method in event object which will return the Object I am going to delete.

event.getSource() and event.getDocument() returns the document. How can I get the object.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow this Event seems to be messed up. In difference to the other `MongoMappingEvent<T>` descendents, this one inherits a `MongoMappingEvent<Document>` through `AbstractDelteEvent<T>`. I cannot explain this difference.

But as I also was in need to retrive the Documents before deleting them, I used the debugger to find, it is possible to retrive the Document Ids, using some hackish shit undocumented get("Key")-chain.

```
event.getDocument()
     .get("_id", Document.class)      // BSON Document!
     .getList("$in", ObjectId.class)  // ObjectId.class or what ever Type your Id is.
```

With that you can retrive a list of the ids of your documents. Take the repository or what ever, and use those ids to fetch the documents.

---

I do really not like using those string-key-things that I have not found in a documentation, as who knows when they will be removed.
I would love to remove this answer as soon as someone provides a less hackish way.

> Be aware, that when you are using an `@EventHandler`, it can not consider the type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.8.x/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/event/BeforeDeleteEvent.html)

> The DBObject held in the event will represent the query document before being mapped based on the domain class handled.

Well, since deletion query doesn't have to contain all the document, it may contain only certain field of your class, and not necessarily the document's ID